# TableRow.get("field_name") can only be cast to String in Dataflow ParDo

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am exporting a table from BQ by dataflow and it seems when processed by ParDo, I could only get the "string" value of data of each field in `TableRow` regardless of what originally the data type is in BQ schema.

For example, say my table has a `INTEGER` typed column "fieldA":

```
     public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
         TableRow row = c.element();
         String str = (String) c.get("fieldA"); // OK
         Integer i = (Integer) c.get("fieldA"); // Throw "String cannot be cast to Integer" exception
     }
```

Is it a bug or it is only me? If not only me, is there anyway to get around it? For integer type I could still do `Integer.valueOf(String)` but it will have to be a little bit hacky and err-prone when parsing `Timestamp` field.

FYI, I am using BlockDataflowPipelineRunner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [BigQueryTableRowIterator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/util/BigQueryTableRowIterator.java#L216):

> Note that integers are encoded as strings to match BigQuery's exported JSON format.

So you'll need to `Integer.parseInt`. Sorry for the trouble, we should improve the documentation about typing of values in the `TableRow` when reading from `BigQueryIO.Read` - this documentation is not very discoverable.

Comment: ahh i think my question is that the "fieldA" is of type INTEGER in bq schema at the first place but in ParDo it is returning String type nevertheless

Comment: If you are sure that the field's type in the schema is INTEGER but ParDo gives you a String, that sounds like a bug. Is this a batch or streaming pipeline? Which runner are you using? (direct / Dataflow / spark or flink?)

Comment: and sorry i didn't make this clear but what happen to me is that `TableRow.get()` is returning string regardless of BQ schema. With BQ schema type timestamp for example, in ParDo it is still returning string type as well

Comment: Also, what version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: i am running a batch job with `BlockingDataflowPipelineRunner` with sdk 1.3.0

Comment: Apologies, my initial answer was wrong. I updated the answer.

Comment: Also note that "Integer" in BigQuery is 64-bits, so you need to use `Long.parseLong` to parse these. For reference, types are defined here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/preparing-data-for-bigquery#datatypes